# Only the top most switch works in my website

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, input

I'm using HTML, PHP and Ajax to toggle switch in my website. However, only the top most switch is functional. The reason why I use PHP is to display results from my DB, and Ajax is there to toggle switch without reloading the website. Thanks in advance and comment for any questions!

[Photo Here :D I have three rows in the DB. Data retrieve fine. Top button works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbJCx.png)

ps : removed all classes for simplicity

About main.php and recipe.inc.php. They are separated because recipe.inc.php is used in many documents.

**main.php**

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect(localhost,****,****,loginsystem);
   //DB connection
   $query="SELECT * FROM `recipe` WHERE creator='$uid'";
   //SQL Query
   $results = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
   $array = array();
   //Array to save key column of the result in order
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($row[recipe_ID]); $i++) {
         $array[$i] = $row[recipe_ID];
         echo '<input type="hidden" id="recipe_ID" name="recipe_ID" value="';
         echo $array[$i];
         echo '">';
    //might confuse you. this is just to hand over recipe_ID to recipe.inc.php
         echo  '<li>';
         echo  '<label>';
           if($row[status]==1){
            echo  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkStatus" name="checkStatus" checked="">';
    //In case where row[status] is equal to 1. means it's ON
                    }else{
            echo  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkStatus" name="checkStatus">';
    //OFF otherwise
                    }
         echo  '<span class="switcher-indicator"></span>';
         echo  '</label>';
         echo  '</li>';
         }
     } 
   ?>
```

**recipe.inc.php**

```
    <?php            
    if(isset($_POST['checkStatus'])){
    $recipe_ID = $_POST['recipe_ID']);

    if($_POST['checkStatus']=='ON'){
    $status = 1; //to save in DB as boolean. if ON->1
    }else if($_POST['checkStatus']=='OFF'){
    $status = 0; //if OFF->0
    }

  $sql = "UPDATE `recipe` SET `status`=$status WHERE creator=$uid AND recipe_ID=$recipe_ID";
    //nev
  mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }
    ?>
```

and the Ajax part is saved in another js file.
**recipe.js**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#checkStatus').on('click', function() {
        var checkStatus = this.checked ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
        var recipe_ID = $("#recipe_ID").val();
        $.post("loginsystem/includes/recipe.inc.php", {
          "checkStatus": checkStatus,
          "recipe_ID": recipe_ID
        },
        function(data) {
            $('#checkStatus').html(data);
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: + I have tried putting alert in js file. Here is the result.
1st button : works. alert. status changes
2nd and 3rd button: no alert. status reamins the same.

Comment: Side note: This is open to an sql injection; use a prepared statement.

Comment: Funk Forty Ninet / Thanks for the comment. This is just for my school project, however, I'll take your advise in case anything happens :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like all the switches have the same ID. If that is the case, only the first one will work.

Try changing your code to look like this:

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect(localhost,****,****,loginsystem);
   //DB connection
   $query="SELECT * FROM `recipe` WHERE creator='$uid'";
   //SQL Query
   $results = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
   $cnt = 1;
   $array = array();
   //Array to save key column of the result in order
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
       for ($i = 0; $i < count($row[recipe_ID]); $i++) {
         $array[$i] = $row[recipe_ID];
         echo '<input type="hidden" id="recipe_ID-' .$cnt. '" name="recipe_ID" value="';   <============== HERE
         echo $array[$i];
         echo '">';
    //might confuse you. this is just to hand over recipe_ID to recipe.inc.php
         echo  '<li>';
         echo  '<label>';
           if($row[status]==1){
            echo  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkStatus-' .$cnt. '" name="checkStatus" checked="">'; //<============== HERE
    //In case where row[status] is equal to 1. means it's ON
                    }else{
            echo  '<input type="checkbox" id="checkStatus-' .$cnt. '" name="checkStatus">'; //<================ HERE
    //OFF otherwise
                    }
         echo  '<span class="switcher-indicator"></span>';
         echo  '</label>';
         echo  '</li>';
         }
     $cnt++; <=========== HERE
     } 
?>
```

Comment: In your jQuery, also, you will need a way to catch the click event for all those different IDs. Wouldn't it be great if there was a way to trap the click event for all IDs that **start with** the same string of characters, and then separate-off teh part that is different? Well, there is: check out `$('[id^=checkStatus]').click()`. That will catch a click on any element that starts with "checkStatus" - then you can strip off the numeric part of the ID by splitting it into an array and choosing the 2nd part: `let num = $(this).split("-")[1]`

Comment: By the way, there was nothing at all wrong with your question. I don't know why someone downvoted you (I see someone else corrected that, so the net to you is +8 rep). On SO, don't take downvoting personally - there are many guys who downvote "just because they can". Keep asking questions, learn, and ask more questions. Ignore the downvotes. Just ask.

Comment: gibberish // I try to make my question crystal clear because English is not my mother tongue so I review my post several times before I post it. I thought there was something wrong with my English again or someone that hates codes that are open to SQL injection. Thank you again, I'll keep posting question that might help others as well. Moreover, I'm sorry that my rep is low that I cannot upvote your answer!